# Watson conversations- Adding to a current total

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm having trouble updating the current total. This is my current syntax:

```
"Current_Total": "<? $Money_Need + $Current_Total>?"
```

Additional Information:

```
"Money_Need": "<? $Money_Goal- $Money_Saved?>"
```

Both `$Money_Goal` and `$Money_Saved` are given by user input and stored `"@sys-number.numeric_value"`

I've also tried making `Current_Total.numeric_value` or setting `Current_Total` to `0` first.

Comment: What is the error you are hitting with?

Comment: I'm getting a dialog node error: Error when updating context with context of dialog node id [node_1_1489106934771]. Dialog Node context is [{"Current_Total":"<? $Money_Need.toInt() + $Current_Total.toInt()>?"}] org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1070E:(pos 1): Problem parsing left operand (and there is 1 more error in the log)

Comment: Not sure if it is because of your closing angle bracket..Angle bracket has to be after the ?(question mark) "Current_Total":"<? $Money_Need.toInt() + $Current_Total.toInt() ?>"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"Current_Total": "<? $Money_Need.toInt() + $Current_Total.toInt()>?"`

That is a way how to make super sure Conversation service will treat those as numbers.